# Repeated Measures Test for Comparing Devices With Multiple Samples

Tags: repeated-measures, bland-altman-plot

I ran an experiment using the same device, under two attachment conditions. The first condition was “loose” and the second condition was “tight.”

I tested the device on 8 subjects under both conditions. I collected 10 device readings for each subject for each condition.

I’m wondering what is the best way to analyze the data. I know Bland and Altman proposed a way to do this (2007) but there’s also some information on using random effects modelling to include the within-subject variability (Myles and Cui, 2007).

I’m interested in whether or not tightness influences the variance in the device reading or if the mean device reading was different (systemically higher per se) in one condition or the other.

A simple paired T-test will do the trick for the means, but I want to look at variance too.